# Right Click in Kali Linux 2.0 using touchpad

Tags: kali-linux, touchpad

I can't *right click* on Kali Linux 2.0 with my laptop's touchpad.

Comment: Have you tried holding the touchpad?

Comment: Doesn't seem unclear to me --- I have precisely the same problem. Two finger clicking doesn't do anything and I can't find any options to enable it.

Answer (score 0):

On a Macbook Air, clicking with two fingers on the pad appears to work for me.